# Regular expression for film rating

Tags: regex

I know next to nothing about regular expressions and after reading tutorials on several sites, still know next to nothing. I want a regular expression that will validate/enforce that a film rating is one of G, PG-13, R or NC-17.

Comment: Why use a regular expression for this? Just put them in an array or dictionary and test whether the given value is in the array/dict.

Comment: As @Barmar suggested above, you can have an array `['G', 'PG-13', 'R', 'NC-17']` and check if the value you are looking for matches one of the elements in the array. You don't need any specific regex there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the programming language you're using, but you don't need a regex, i.e.:

for `python`:

```
ratings = ['G','PG-13','R','NC-17']
rating = "PG-13"
if rating in ratings:
    print "ranking exist"
else:
    print "no match"
```

---

for `php`:

```
$ratings = array('G','PG-13','R','NC-17');
$rating = 'PG-13';

if (in_array($rating, $ratings)) 
{
    print "rating exist";
} else {
    print "no match";
}
```